# problem with shortcodes nesting

Tags: shortcode

I am developing a wp theme and I want to have a shortcode that can be used serveral times from within an article.

in functions.php i have:

```
function twoColPostcardfn($atts, $content){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'image'=>'',
        'text'=>'',
        'title'=>'',
        'boxlink'=>'',
        'float'=>''
        ), $atts));
    $bob='<span class="twoColPostcard ">'.$content.'</span>';
    return $bob;
}
add_shortcode( 'twoColPostcard', 'twoColPostcardfn' );
```

in the article I have:

```
<p>[twoColPostcard]</p>
<p>hello from the first postcard</p>
<p>[/twoColPostcard]</p>
<p>[twoColPostcard]</p>
<p>hello from the second postcard</p>
<p>[/twoColPostcard]</p>
```

And I want my output to be

```
<span class="twoColPostcard"><p>Hello from ...</p></span>
<span class="twoColPostcard"><p>Hello from ...</p></span>
```

But instead I am getting:

```
<span class="twoColPostcard">
<p></p>
<p>hello from the first postcard</p>
<p><span class="twoColPostcard "></span></p>
<p>hello from the second postcard</p>
<p></p>
</span>
```

In other words the second shortcode is begun before the first one is finished so the are ending up nested (and the 2nd one is empty)

I used the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes) to help but its not working and I don't know why. I have tried inserting this into my functions [as per](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175025/wraping-content-into-link-with-shortcodes) to no avail

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the remove filter to be called first like this, change your `span` to `div` or you will have issues with some browsers:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);

function twoColPostcardfn($atts, $content){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'image'=>'',
        'text'=>'',
        'title'=>'',
        'boxlink'=>'',
        'float'=>''
        ), $atts));
    $bob='<div class="twoColPostcard ">'.$content.'</div>';
    return $bob;
}
add_shortcode( 'twoColPostcard', 'twoColPostcardfn' );
```

or change the content to another `span`, the `p` tag is a block tag and the `span` tag is an inline tag, a block tag cant be inside an inline one.

```
[twoColPostcard]<span>hello from the first postcard</span>[/twoColPostcard]
[twoColPostcard]<span>hello from the second postcard</span>[/twoColPostcard]
```

Comment: yes - that's it!!! Its working fine now. Put divs instead of spans and it all is well. (Also tried to remove as many of those darn <p>...</p> by reducing the number of line-breaks. But stupid me for putting block level elements inside inline - kinda lesson1! THANKS so much David!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding unnecessary `<p>` tags around your shortcodes. Try this instead:

```
[twoColPostcard]<p>hello from the first postcard</p>[/twoColPostcard]
[twoColPostcard]<p>hello from the second postcard</p>[/twoColPostcard]
```

Comment: but you were right!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why use p tags at all? Don't enter any new lines and p tags won't be added. Just add it all on line:

```
[twoColPostcard]hello from the first postcard[/twoColPostcard[twoColPostcard]hello from the second postcard[/twoColPostcard]
```

And then change your shortcode to include the p tags:

```
function twoColPostcardfn($atts, $content){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'image'=>'',
    'text'=>'',
    'title'=>'',
    'boxlink'=>'',
    'float'=>''
    ), $atts));
$bob='<span class="twoColPostcard "><p>'.$content.'</p></span>';
return $bob;
}
add_shortcode( 'twoColPostcard', 'twoColPostcardfn' );
```

Comment: thanks - If I do as you suggest the nesting is right. But what if I want html inside the shortcode?